# How to deploy Hyperledger fabric on Openstack cloud?

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, openstack

I am working on Hyperledger Fabric for a time being. I want to deploy my Hyperledger to a cloud platform but only public cloud like AWS and Azure are supporting Hyperledger. So how can I deploy Hyperledger on private and opensource cloud like OpenStack?

I have come up with a way by first deploy it on kubernetes and then kubernetes on openstack. Can I do like this or is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

Hyper ledger fabric framework is a group of containers. So you choose any one cloud service to deploy with docker. The best way to use for deployment of HLF is the Kubernetes services. And there are other many services like IBM blockchain platform, Fablo which provide easy deployment and maintenance of the network with good documentation.

https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/fablo

https://www.ibm.com/blockchain/platform